# Is there a way to set the index name in the DataFrame constructor?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is it possible to set the index name inside the `pd.DataFrame()` constructor instead of the way I'm doing it below?

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'s': [-1], 'count':[1]}, index = pd.date_range('2022-02-07', periods=1))

In [2]: index = df.index

In [3]: index.name = 'Date'

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
            s  count
Date
2022-02-07 -1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `name` parameter in `date_range`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'s': [-1], 'count':[1]}, 
                   index = pd.date_range('2022-02-07', periods=1, name='Date'))
print (df)
            s  count
Date                
2022-02-07 -1      1
```

Or use `rename`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'s': [-1], 'count':[1]}, 
                   index = pd.date_range('2022-02-07', periods=1).rename('Date'))
```

Comment: @mozway - ya, already in bookmarks